# Haskell: Finding the type of an expression involving map

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am trying to find the type of the following Haskell expression:

```
map (\x -> x + 1)
```

Since the map function is partially applied, it will return another function.

In GHCI, the type of the function that is returned is:

```
let res = map (\x -> x + 1)
:t res
map (\x -> x + 1) :: Num b => [b] -> [b]
```

Would the type of the above expression be the type of the function that is returned? Any insights are appreciated.

Comment: Yep.  Yes. Uh huh. For sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is the type of the function which is returned.

But how does GHC figure this out? Well, let's look at the type of just plain `map`:

```hs
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

And now let's look at the type of `\x -> x + 1`:

```hs
(\x -> x + 1) :: Num n => n -> n
```

(In case you don't know yet, this means that it converts `n` to `n`, where `n` can be any type which is an instance of `Num` i.e. `n` is any number type.)

So matching up the types, we get:

```hs
map           ::         (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
(\x -> x + 1) :: Num n => n -> n
```

So:

```hs
map (\x -> x + 1) :: Num n => [n] -> [n]
```

Which is the same as what GHCi reports.